# Why is a VerifyError thrown when publishing changes with a decorated HtmlResponseWriter

Tags: jsf-2, decorator, verifyerror

I am facing a problem when publishing changes to WebSphere with JSF2 (Myfaces 2.0.12).

Everytime I publish a change to my local server (WebSphere) I am getting a java.lang.VerifyError. After a full restart of the server the application runs smoothly with my changes.

```
java.lang.VerifyError: com/sun/faces/renderkit/html_basic/HtmlResponseWriter.startElement(Ljava/lang/String;Ljavax/faces/component/UIComponent;)V
```

The StackTrace indicates that something is wrong with the ResponseWriter and indeed we changed a little bit there ;-)
For accessibility-reasons I have to have full controll of the HTML so I need custom HtmlRenderers. To reduce duplicate code I decorated the ResponseWriter I get from the FacesContext with my own, and provide additional convenience-methods on top.

```
public class CustomResponseWriter<T extends UIInput & MyFormdataInterface> extends HtmlResponseWriter
{

    public CustomResponseWriter(ReponseWriter writer){
        super(writer, writer.getContentType(), writer.getCharacterEncoding());
    }

    public writeFancy(T component)
    {
    ...
        writeText(component.getMyFanceAttribute(), null);
    ...
    }
}
```

As I said, the code runs fine after the server was restarted so I assume the code is correct. But on the other side, this error occurs only on pages where I use this CustomReponseWriter.

Is there anything wrong with the idea of decorating the ResponseWriter in a new class? Or might this just be a problem in WebSphere?

Comment: It should be some problem with your classpath, because the error is thrown from a com/sun/faces class (Mojarra), but you said MyFaces is used. Create a class that extends from impl classes is not a good idea, but it is valid. Maybe use delegation pattern is better in this case.

Comment: It worked! Changing the decorator to a delegate resolved the problem. I do like the decorator more, since I dont have to implement/delegate all methods from ResponseWriter but it wasnt that much work. Would be nice to know why I cannot decorate a ResponseWriter.

Answer (score 0):

As lu4242 mentioned in his comment, I changed the implementation from decorator to a delegate and the problem disappeared. It would be nice to understand why this happens but for now here is the changed code (I dont like the verbose code from the delegate in this case but as long as it works).

```
public class CustomResponseWriter<T extends UIInput & MyFormdataInterface> extends ResponseWriter
{
    private ResponseWriter delegateWriter;

    public CustomResponseWriter(ReponseWriter writer){
        this.delegateWriter = writer;
    }

    public writeFancy(T component)
    {
    ...
        writeText(component.getMyFanceAttribute(), null);
    ...
    }

    public String getContentType()
    {
        this.delegateWriter.getContentType();
    }

    //... and so on for all methods from ResponseWriter...
}
```

}